# Searching Movie name in the Download URL

Tags: java, regex

We require to verify, if the given URL has `searchStringKeyword` using regular expression.

for example

```
if URL : http://thepiratebay.org/torrent/3962906/Mera.Naam.Joker.1970.LiMiTED.DVDRiP.XviD-D3Si"

searchStringKeyword : Mera Naam Joker
expected outcome: true

searchStringKeyword : DVDRiP
expected outcome: true

searchStringKeyword : Speed
expected outcome: false
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Amit

Comment: Another BitTorrent client is *exactly* what the world needs.

Answer (score 1):

Your examples aren't quite comprehensive.

If you want to match any URL with the words "Mera", "Naam", and "Joker", in that order, but with any number of characters separating them, you could use [this](http://rubular.com/r/Dnn8zwuuQr):

```
/Mera.*Naam.*Joker/
```

If you want there to be one and only one separating character, but you don't care what that character is, you could use [this](http://rubular.com/r/JBl2C3SDtG):

```
/Mera.Naam.Joker/
```

If you want there to be a single `.` character between the words, like [this](http://rubular.com/r/wDHXwOBhNj):

```
/Mera\.Naam\.Joker/
```

Comment: Hi, i tried below: </br>String s_url = "http://thepiratebay.org/torrent/3962906/Mera.Naam.Joker.1970.LiMiTED.DVDRiP.XviD-D3Si";</br>
   String regex = "/DVDRip/";</br>
   String regex_name = "/Mera\\.Naam\\.Joker/";</br>
   
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);</br>
   Matcher m = p.matcher(s_url);</br>
   System.out.println("Found DVD in url  "+m.matches());</br></br>
   
   Pattern pp = Pattern.compile(regex_name);</br>
   Matcher mm = pp.matcher(s_url);</br>
   System.out.println("Found name in url  "+mm.matches());</br> but above both returns false.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using regex à la PERL, the patterns would be these :

```
/DVDRip/
/Mera\W+Naam\W+Joker/
/Speed/
```